# MVC @Html.ActionLink ID for hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I need to be able to create an `id` for a hyperlink.
I have the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @item.ID}, new {id = "deletelink"})
```

I was wondering, if there is any better way of doing this? Note that the `id` will be `deletelink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you looking for exactly? Are you not able to use this? This is the correct way to create an action link except that it  looks malformed. You're not using the correct overload. You need to add in your controller name.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "ControllerName", new { id = @item.ID}, new {id = "deletelink"})
```